# SQL Joins/Doctrine/Symfony2: Only getting one result from join when I expect multiple

Tags: php, sql, symfony, join, doctrine

So, i got some data which is meant to display a certain ingredient (ingredient table), and that it can have different names (ingredient_name table). Here's some mock data:

```
ingredient
id | mock_name
-------------
1  | "The First Ingredient"
2  | "The second Ingredient"


ingredient_name
--------------
id | ingredient_id | name
1  | 2             | "Milk"
2  | 2             | "Mjolk"
3  | 1             | "Steak"
```

So what I want to happen is that the user inserts an ingredient ID, and it outputs the ingredient data (in this case "ingredient.mock_name" and the ingredient aliases (ingredient_name.name).

I've already set up all the entities, repositories etc with Symfony/Doctrine. This is what I have right now:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$query = $em->createQuery(
  'SELECT I, IGN.name
  FROM AppBundle:IngredientName IGN
  INNER JOIN AppBundle:Ingredient I WITH IGN.ingredientID=I.id
  WHERE IGN.ingredientID=:ingID'
)->setParameters(['ingID' => 2]);
$ingredients = $query->getResult();
```

That gives me this result:

```
   {  
      "0":{  
         "id":2,
         "mock_name":"The second Ingredient",
      },
      "name":"Mjolk"
   }
```

What I was hoping to get was something like:

```
   {  
      "0":{  
         "id":2,
         "mock_name":"The second Ingredient",
      },
      "name":"Mjolk",
      "name":"Milk" <---- This value also
   }
```

SQL joins has never been my strong side, and thinking with doctrine is not making things easier. Anyone here able to point me in the right direction?

---

It's something like this I want, but only with one SQL statement, if thats possible:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
  'SELECT IGN.name
  FROM AppBundle:IngredientName IGN
  INNER JOIN AppBundle:Ingredient I WITH IGN.ingredientID=I.id
  WHERE IGN.ingredientID=:ingID'
)->setParameters(['ingID' => $ingredientIdentifier]);
$ingredientsNames = $query->getResult();



$query = $em->createQuery(
  'SELECT I
  FROM AppBundle:IngredientName IGN
  INNER JOIN AppBundle:Ingredient I WITH IGN.ingredientID=I.id
  WHERE IGN.ingredientID=:ingID'
)->setParameters(['ingID' => $ingredientIdentifier]);
$ingredients = $query->getResult();


$ingredients = array_merge($ingredients, ['ingredientNames' => $ingredientsNames]);
```

returns:

```
{  
   "0":{  
      "id":2,
      "mock_name":"The second Ingredient"
   },
   "ingredientNames":[  
      {  
         "name":"Milk"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Mjolk"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Symfony/Doctrine, but looking at your json result, it's not possible to have the same key repeated twice.

I believe "name": "Milk" was retrieved at first, but was later overwritten by "name": "Mjolk".